# Integrate a function of $\cos(x)$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I wish to calculate $\int_0^{2\pi} \cfrac{dx}{(1-2 t\cos x+t)^2}$ for $|t|<1$.

I already know that $\int_0^{2\pi} \cfrac{dx}{1+k\cos x}=\cfrac{2\pi}{\sqrt{1-k^{2}}}$ for $|k|<1$

and  that $\left|\cfrac{1}{(1-2t\cos x+t)^2}\right| \leq \left| \cfrac{1}{1+k\cos x} \right|$.

I also know that the answer is $\cfrac{2\pi}{1-t^{2}}$.

How can I get this answer? Is there any theorem such as the series comparison test for integrals?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This integral is improper for some values of $t$ (if I am not wrong, for $t > 1/3$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{dx}{(1-2t\cos x+t)^2} &= \oint_{|z| = 1} \frac{1}{(1-2t (z+z^{-1})/2 + t)^2} \frac{dz}{iz} \\
&= -\oint_{|z| = 1}\frac{iz}{(t z^2-tz-z + t)^2}\,dz
\end{align*}

$$z = \frac{t+1 \pm \sqrt{-3t^2+2t+1}}{2t}$$

Now with the restriction $|t|<1$, find which root(s) are in the contour $|z|<1$ and use residue theorem to evaluate the integral.

Answer (score 0):

One proof could be by replacing cos x for (e^ix+e^-ix)/2 and using Cauchy residue theorem

Comment: Not even an answer. I would like the exact derivation.

Comment: this is not a math class parcly

Comment: But you have not shown how the Cauchy residue theorem allows you to derive the given answer.